# Ways to merge managed object contexts

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I use concurrency in Core Data. Apple docs like [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdChangeManagement.html) often told me that synchronization of the contexts depends on the semantics of my application. And I can't found concrete samples how to merge `UIManagedObjectContext`s.
So in my app one `UIManagedObject` may have different property values in different contexts. I need to merge contexts by replacing objects or updating its properties.
Here's my code:

```
- (void)__saveToMainContext
{
    if ([_context_ hasChanges])
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![_context_ save:&error])
        {
            if (error.code == NSManagedObjectMergeError)
            {
                for (NSMergeConflict* conflict in [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"conflictList"])
                {
                    [_context_ refreshObject:[conflict sourceObject] mergeChanges:YES];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this method creates duplicates objects.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you should just pick up the merge policy you prefer and set it in the **NSManagedObjectContexts**, [like the doc says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html).

You will be able to decide whether to keep the local changes, the storage once and so on:

```
enum {
   NSErrorMergePolicyType                      = 0x00,
   NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType  = 0x01,
   NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType = 0x02,
   NSOverwriteMergePolicyType                  = 0x03,
   NSRollbackMergePolicyType                   = 0x04
};
```

But I guess you already know this things. Once I wrote an category to more easily handle those circumstances, you can find the [implementation code here](http://www.ipaste.org/hCj). I myself found part of it somewhere in the cyberspace, but I can't find it back now and thus I cannot cite the other author.
**BUT** my seggestion is always: avoid handling this manually. It's a real pain in the ass. I found really comfortable using [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) for CoreData management, it works like a charme.

Comment: I saw this docs, but I don't understand which context mergePolicy I need to set to NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType. And what to do if an error occurs? Why any error occur, when I have set mergePolicy?

Comment: which policy did you set? and how? can you paste some more code? And the merge policy has to be set in the managed object context. It will then decide how this context data will be merged with the persistent storage data